# Unable to fetch particular line based on a string

Tags: python, regex

file1.txt:

```
" > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
            " > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
            "Checking out Revision ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a (refs/remotes/origin/master)",
            " > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10",
          " > git checkout -f ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
            " > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10",
            " > git checkout -b master ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
            """Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins"""",
            "[Pipeline] sh",
            "[petclinic] Running shell script",
```

I am reading the file content to a variable: `message` and want to fetch mentioned line:

```
Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins
```

I am using Python 2.7 I tried using :

```
indexofGitMsgList = [gin for gin, item in enumerate(message) if re.search('^Commit Message', item)]
indexofGitMsg = max(indexofGitMsgList)
gitMsgList = message[indexofGitMsg]
print(gitMsgList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex --> `Lookbehind & Lookahead`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

message = '''" > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
            " > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
            "Checking out Revision ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a (refs/remotes/origin/master)",
            " > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10",
          " > git checkout -f ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
            " > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10",
            " > git checkout -b master ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
            """Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins"""",
            "[Pipeline] sh",
            "[petclinic] Running shell script",'''

m = re.search("(?<=Commit message:)(.*?)(?=,)", message)
if m:
    print(m.group(1).strip().strip('"'))
```

**Output:**

```
Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `in` to search for the `str` and `replace()` to get rid of the `"`:

list.txt:

```
" > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
" > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10",
"Checking out Revision ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a (refs/remotes/origin/master)",
" > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10",
" > git checkout -f ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
" > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10",
" > git checkout -b master ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
"""Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins"""",
"[Pipeline] sh",
"[petclinic] Running shell script",
```

**Hence**:

```
logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

searchStr = 'Commit message'

for line in content:
    if searchStr in line:
        print(line.replace('"', '')[:-1])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Commit message: Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins
```

**EDIT**:

To store the message in a variable:

```
searchStr = 'Commit message'
commitMsg = ''
for line in content:
    if searchStr in line:
        print(line.replace('"', '')[:-1])
        commitMsg = line.replace('"', '').split(": ")[1][:-1]

print(commitMsg)   # Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple example would be to check if the line contains three double quotes (""") and save it in the list.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    message = []
    for line in f.readlines():
    if '"""' in line:
        message.append(line)
    print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the easiest way, use `findall` method of regex from python:

```
import re
message = '''" > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # 
    timeout=10",
        " > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # 
    timeout=10",
        "Checking out Revision ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a 
    (refs/remotes/origin/master)",
        " > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10",
      " > git checkout -f ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
        " > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10",
        " > git checkout -b master 
    ff1b75913a79ffe7fc066bc962f74afa5e6f563a",
        """Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins"""",
        "[Pipeline] sh",
        "[petclinic] Running shell script",'''


m=(re.findall("Commit message:\s.+[a-zA-Z]+",message))
for i in m:
   print(i)
```

**Output**

```
Commit message: "Added parameter for jmeter for Jenkins
```

Comment: am getting following error:
`indexofGitMsgList = [gin for gin, item in enumerate(message) if re.search("(?<=Commit message:)(.*?)(?=,)", item)]
  File "/opt/stackstorm/virtualenvs/core_pack/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
"`

Comment: hey u cannot use this statement in the if, because it does not return anything of type bool, string : it returns the re.match type which cannot be accepted in your if. please try changing its type or use if str(re.findall("Commit message:\s.+[a-zA-Z]+",item)).strip('[]\'')